# ggplot2 - using two different color scales for overlayed plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, color-scheme

I am attempting to overlay two different plots. One is `geom_boxplot`, the other `geom_jitter`.  I would like each to have its own color scale.   But when I add the second color scale, I am given the error

```
 "Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', 
  which will replace the existing scale."
```

I am assuming I am doing something wrong.  Any advice would be appreciate

This is a rough example of my working code:

```
P <-  ggplot(dat) + 
          geom_boxplot(aes(x=ve, y=metValue, fill=metric), alpha=.35, w=0.6, notch=FALSE, na.rm = TRUE) + 
          scale_fill_manual(values=cpalette1) + 
          geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="#DD4466", linetype = "longdash") +
          theme(legend.position="none")

P + geom_jitter(dat2, aes(x=ve, y=metValue, fill=atd), 
                size=2, shape=4, alpha = 0.4, 
                position = position_jitter(width = .03, height=0.03), na.rm = TRUE) + 
              scale_fill_manual(values=cpalette2)
```

`dat` and `dat2` have the same schema, but different values.

I found several examples addressing overlaying graphs but none that appeared to address this specific concern.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, made two sample data frames with the same names as in example.

```
dat<-data.frame(ve=rep(c("FF","GG"),times=50),
                metValue=rnorm(100),metric=rep(c("A","B","D","C"),each=25),
                atd=rep(c("HH","GG"),times=50))
dat2<-data.frame(ve=rep(c("FF","GG"),times=50),
                metValue=rnorm(100),metric=rep(c("A","B","D","C"),each=25),
                atd=rep(c("HH","GG"),times=50))
```

I assume that you do not need to use argument `fill=` in the `geom_jitter()` because color for `shape=4` can be set also with `colour=` argument. Then you can use `scale_colour_manual()` to set  your values. Instead of `cpallete` just used names of colors.

```
P <-  ggplot(dat) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=ve, y=metValue, fill=metric), alpha=.35, w=0.6, notch=FALSE, na.rm = TRUE) +  
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="#DD4466", linetype = "longdash") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue","green","yellow"))+
  theme(legend.position="none")

P + geom_jitter(data=dat2, aes(x=ve, y=metValue, colour=atd), 
                size=2, shape=4, alpha = 0.4, 
                position = position_jitter(width = .03, height=0.03), na.rm = TRUE) + 
                scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","blue"))
```

[image]