# ggplot2 - using two different color scales for same fill in overlayed plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

A very similar question to the one [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011422/ggplot2-using-two-different-color-scales-for-overlayed-plots). However, in that situation the fill parameter for the two plots are different. For my situation the fill parameter is the same for both plots, but I want different color schemes.

I would like to manually change the color in the boxplots and the scatter plots (for example making the boxes white and the points colored).

Example:

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

n<-4*3*10
myvalues<- rexp((n))
days    <- ntile(rexp(n),4)
doses   <- ntile(rexp(n), 3)

test    <- data.frame(values =myvalues, 
                      day = factor(days,   levels = unique(days)),
                      dose = factor(doses, levels = unique(doses)))

p<- ggplot(data = test, aes(x = day, y = values)) + 
    geom_boxplot( aes(fill = dose))+
    geom_point(   aes(fill = dose), alpha = 0.4, 
    position = position_jitterdodge())
```

produces a plot like this:
[image]

Using 'scale_fill_manual()' overwrites the aesthetic on both the boxplot and the scatterplot.

I have found a hack by adding 'colour' to geom_point and then when I use scale_fill_manual() the scatter point colors are not changed:

```
p<- ggplot(data = test, aes(x = day, y = values)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = dose), outlier.shape = NA)+
    geom_point(aes(fill = dose, colour = factor(test$dose)),
             position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.1))+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('white', 'white', 'white'))
```

[image: This is What I want]

Are there more efficient ways of getting the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group` to set the different boxplots. No need to set the fill and then overwrite it:

```
ggplot(data = test, aes(x = day, y = values)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(group = interaction(day, dose)), outlier.shape = NA)+
    geom_point(aes(fill = dose, colour = dose),
             position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.1))
```

And you should never use `data$column` inside `aes` - just use the bare column. Using `data$column` will work in simple cases, but will break whenever there are `stat` layers or facets.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, Thank you. Somehow I had remained ignorant about interaction() until now in my brief R/ggplot career.

Comment: `interaction` isn't commonly used - but this is the sort of thing it's intended for. Anything that sticks variables together will work here. A lot of people will just use `paste` or `paste0` (which, in this simple case, isn't really any different).